# passing parameters to applets

Tags: java, applet

I am trying out some applet examples from the book "JAVA:THE COMPLETE REFERENCE BY HERBERT SCHILDT". I came across this applet example which is to scroll a text from right to left in the applet window and for some reason it is not taking the parameter value. Where am i going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
package applet1;

import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

/*
<applet code="ParamBanner" width=300 height=80>
<param name=message value="Valar Morghulis">
</applet>
*/

public class ParamBanner extends Applet implements Runnable
{
    String msg;
    Thread t;
    boolean stopFlag;

    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setForeground(Color.white);
    }

    @Override
    public void start()
    {
        msg = getParameter("message");
        if(msg == null)
            msg = "Not Found";
        msg = "" + msg;
        t = new Thread(this);
        stopFlag = false;
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        char ch;

        for(;;)
        {
            try
            {
                repaint();
                Thread.sleep(250);
                ch = msg.charAt(0);
                msg = msg.substring(1,msg.length());
                msg += ch;
                if(stopFlag)
                    break;
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {}
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop()
    {
        t = null;
        stopFlag = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString(msg,10,30);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going wrong by using Applets, see [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets?](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/) and [Moving to a free plugin web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web) posts. Also, stop using AWT, it's a dead technology, move on to `JApplet` or `Swing` at least. It doesn't take the value because your browser is blocking the Applet, for security reasons all browsers these days block them, so Applets are useless now

Comment: Thank you. I understand that applets are dead but i like to learn anything from the most basic topic possible and also that applets are included in my syllabus(rather unfortunately,if we believe the link you shared in your answer). Again,Thank you.This was pretty helpful :) Also would like to add that the next chapters are JApplet and Swing so i'll be heading there soon :D